# Connecting to a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net, sql-server-2012-express

I installed Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server Express 2012. Then I created a new database in SQL Server Management Studio.

Can someone tell me how to connect to this database from Visual Studio (the type of project is not relevant) and start working.

Comment: How would you like to use the data? Entity Framework, ADO .NET, ETc?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Questions such as these tend to get closed for being too general.  There are tons of tutorials on the web to get you started, then if you have a problem with code you have written you can come back and ask specific questions.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your Server Explorer. You will be able to create data connections, and use them, from there.

On the other hand, if you asking how to create a C# program and connect to your database, that's an entirely different question, with a far more complex answer. But a little research on Google should get you started. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) might help if this is what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, I see my database in "Database Connections". So I would like to know how to use the database in my program with ADO.NET.

Comment: @AmerA. That is an entirely different and far more complex question. I suggest you start with the link I provided in my response.

Answer (score 0):

There are options like if you want to add and Entity Framework to your project or you want the simple to the point connection to the database.
Well, in the second case you can follow the steps:

**Go to the server Explorer>>Options to add a conection to the database>> Choose the Server Name>>** and you will be guided.

For using an Entity Framework, you can go through the [Entity Framework Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to connect to SQLSERVER2012 database files from VS2010 server explorer due to the version incompatibility of the database files and the VS2010..